# Please clarify a contradicting closing of question

Tags: discussion

My [question.](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43036/what-are-risks-of-bodybuilding) was closed by JohnP, who told me in comment to narrow it down for it is too broad, but it is closed by JohnP that my question for off-topic to general health and medical advice. What is said and what is done is contradict, which is very confusing and causing problem to me. I asked in comment, and unfortunately not yet answered, so I have no choice to ask here in meta, to get attention and hope some of moderators including who closed it can can help moderate. Would some moderator or someone with reputation higher than 3000 mind explain what happened and confirm what should I do so you will reopen it? Maybe first confirm it's narrowing it down or medical? Then we can discuss accordingly. This ambiguity causes problem to me because

- Officially speaking, even after I narrow it down as said, it can still be shot  down for being off topic for asking for medical discuss and medical advise. Because despite the closing message is private to me only, it is official, and public comment is not.
- Even if I correctly guess what a moderator think that it is about medical, I don't understand it because I didn't ask for treatment or medical advise. I ask for risks, which is a existing tag, health-risk tag. So I am afraid that please someone confirm is it about medical and indicate which part of the question is medical, then I can try to understand and maybe change it.

> As noted, this is an incredibly broad topic, and there are more risks
> and benefits that can be evaluated in a single question. I think there
> could be good information if it were **narrowed down**, but as it is, it's
> too broad to really address well in this form. – JohnP♦ yesterday

> Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting
> answers. Questions on **general health and medical advice are off-topic
> here; you should contact a qualified medical professional instead**.
> Closed 6 hours ago. (Private feedback for you) – Superuser yesterday

Finally, attach my question.

**Are there any risks of bodybuilding?**

> Every exercise has it's features,
> and bodybuilding has it's too. What are risks that these features
> could possibly cause? Or risks from other than these features? If we
> know risks, than we know what to prevent. These common-known features
> are
>
> Bodybuilding is about size and shape.
>
> tedious and repetitive movement
>
> There are easily accessible supplements designed for bodybuilding on
> market.
>
> Heavy weight involves.

Comment: Hello? Do you see this? I am really confused. Please clarify, or I don't know what you want me to to and will have no choice to report this ambiguous and confusing usage of closing privilege to stackexchange meta or somewhere to find some for an reply.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356077/reporting-a-contradict-use-of-closing-question-privilege-and-what-is-the-policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been answered in [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356077/is-there-a-policy-for-a-moderators-to-fix-a-confusing-or-contradict-closing).

You've got two good answers to your question. If they still don't answer your question, learn what you can from them and ask another question with what you still haven't had answered. Editing the question at this point completely invalidates the hard work of two other users.

You can also search the main site to look for other questions that may have the answers you're looking for. Tips for [searching](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/searching) can be found here; I found it a bit cumbersome myself the first few times. Check out the [help](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section for tips on how to write well-scoped questions.

Comment: ? Are you sure I am not allowed to find answer to my own question and post it after i am not answered by the other answers? I think editing now in another problem, which i agree not very good and not my idea. I am asked to do it.

Comment: You can absolutely answer your own question. I meant mainly that editing your question, and then editing your answer as well invalidates the other two users' answers.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Also, isn't asking another question again a duplicate violation? Unless a moderator or a policy can give a clear out like that closed questions or points not yet answered in not included, which I already ask and am waiting for response.